# Using protractor how to check whether an option(e.g "Ping test") is remoed in UI

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, protocol-buffers

In UI, there is an option "Ping Test" which is having id="PingTest" where we can give IP address to test. Suppose the option is removed from the latest build. How to write a protractor test for this option is removed from UI

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isPresent` method to whether the element is present on the page.

```js
expect(await $('#PingTest').isPresent()).toBe(false);
```